# Problems with a variable in component

Tags: angular

Let's see if you can clarify for me because I don't get what I want.
On the one hand I have a Service that offers me an object for a GET request to an API and on the other hand in the component I want to use that service several times to get several responses and save them in an array. But I can't get it because the variable where the number of times the for must be tells me that it is not defined. I put the code to see if they can help me find the error:

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AtresplayerService } from 'src/app/services/atresplayer.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-serie',
  templateUrl: './serie.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./serie.component.css']
})
export class SerieComponent implements OnInit{

  serie: any = {};
  paginas: number
  idsCapitulos: any[] = [];


  constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute, private atresplayer:AtresplayerService) { 

    this.route.params.subscribe(params=>{
      // console.log(params['id']);
      this.getSerie(params['id']);
      this.getCantidadPaginas(params['id']);

    });

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.route.params.subscribe(params=>{
      for (let index = 0; index < this.paginas; index++) {
        this.getIdsCapitulos(params['id'], index);

      }

    });

    console.log(this.idsCapitulos);
  }

  getSerie(id:string){
    this.atresplayer.getSerie(id)
    .subscribe(serie=>{

      this.serie = serie;
    });
  }

  getCantidadPaginas(id:string){
    this.atresplayer.getPaginas(id)
    .subscribe(datos=>{
      // console.log(datos);
      this.paginas = datos;
    });

  }

  getIdsCapitulos(id:string,paginas:number){


    this.atresplayer.getIdCapitulo(id,paginas)
      .subscribe(datos=>{
        this.idsCapitulos.push(datos);
      });

  }








}
```

thanks!

Comment: I don't see any place in your code where you assign a value to `paginas`.
How do you decide how many pages?
For a first shot, try changing `paginas: number;` to `paginas = 2;` and see what happens.

Comment: getCantidadPaginas assing value to paginas. But... I think that proble is by the sync. How i can resolve it?

Comment: Yes, getCantidadPaginas is async, and you are trying to use it's result before it completes. You should investigate the use of of rxjs operators, such as mergeMap or concatMap to make sure that you get the result of getCantidadPaginas before trying to use that result.

Comment: Can you give me an example?